# Please ensure the answer you are voting for does answer the question

Tags: discussion

I just answered my own question incorrectly.

Why did I answer it incorrectly? Because I assumed this answer would work on elementary OS.

But it doesn't. My answer works fine on Ubuntu, but it definitely doesn't solve the issue on elementary OS.

Before anyone even pointed out the fact that my answer doesn't work, I'd received 5 up votes, and 1 down vote. It's since received another up vote.

---

#### When you vote for an answer, check it does answer the question. We need votes. We don't need bad answers.

Comment: link to your post https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/how-can-i-launch-a-command-from-terminal-and-then-close-the-terminal

Comment: I afraid  voting has to be  done based on  post but  not based on person who posted

Comment: fine, let us delete our comments, (which are discussion)?